# (Vim) How do I run settings from vimrc ONLY if it's in gvim?

Tags: vim

How do I make the following settings in my vimrc only run if it's starting gvim?

```
colorscheme slate
set guifont=Consolas:h14
set wrap!
set lines=30 columns=100
set spell
set number
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check you're looking for is `has("gui_running")`:

```
if has("gui_running")
  set wrap!
  set lines=30 columns=100
  set spell
  set number
endif
```

Note, however, that you'll want a different conditional for `guifont`.  That's because the values accepted for that option differ based on the GUI environment.  It looks like you're using a value that's suitable for MacVim, so you might want this:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  set guifont=Consolas:h14
endif
```

If not, you can run `:help setting-guifont` to see appropriate options for your system.